# LDAP multiple or syntax

Tags: java, ldap

I'm hoping this is an easy question for any LDAP experts out there.

I'm using java, SearchDirContext's and a string builder to put together a query that looks like:
 `(|(givenName=smith*)(sn=smith*)(middleName=smith*)(mail=smith*)(telephoneNumber=smith*)(buildingName=smith*)(department=smith*)(major=smith*)(minor=smith*))`. The idea being to allow a user to search with a single string and get results matching any of those attributes.

The query completes successfully but with inaccurate results. For example if I search for myself (I know my record exists)...

- by last name I get no results
- by first name (which there should be hundreds of results for) I get a small subset (9) which does not include my entry.

I would like to first eliminate any possibility for issues with my query, if you would like more information/code snippits of the execution of the code let me know and I can provide it.

Also please keep in mind I am a strong advocate of doing things correctly and am willing to modify any part of my code to make things more efficient.

------------------- (EDIT) So the syntax is correct.... (EDIT)--------------------

Here is some code around my query, maybe this can determine if my results are getting cutoff.

```
      try {
          context = ldapPooler.getContext(); // Returns a custom SearchDirContext object wrapping a javax.naming.DirContext.
          SearchControls controls = new SearchControls();
          controls.setCountLimit(maxResultCount);

          Integer resultCount = 0;

          // They try block is from an example found at
          // http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JNDI-LDAP/howtoperformasearchandlimitthenumberofresultsreturned.htm
          // The goal was to limit the results.

          try {

            logger.debug("Finished w/the search string: " + ldapSearchString);

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> result = context.search("ou=People", ldapSearchString, controls);
            // SearchDirContext.search simply calls DirContext.search with the passed attributes.

            while (result.hasMore()) {
                searchResults.add(result.next());
                resultCount++;
            }
            logger.debug("Found results: " + resultCount);

          } catch (LimitExceededException lee) {

            logger.debug("Caught LimitExceededException w/resultCount: " + resultCount);

            if (resultCount == maxResultCount) {
                logger.debug("Found " + resultCount + " results.");
            } else {
                logger.debug("In the else....not throwing an exception. Found " + resultCount + " results.");
            }

          } finally {
            context.close();
          }
      } catch (NamingException ne) {
        logger.error("Caught a NamingException while gettingContactCardsBySearchString(" + searchString + ")");
        throw new LdapLookupFailedException(ne);
      } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Caught Exception while gettingContactCardsBySearchString(" + searchString + ")");
        throw new LdapLookupFailedException(e);
      }
```

Comment: It's been a while since I've done that, so I'll comment instead of answer: Your query has the form (|()()()) [That is, notice the pipe as second character]. Is it not supposed to be (()()())? Or, if you really want a bunch of or's, (()|()|()) ? Again, it's been a while, but I seem to recall that it uses a regular expression type of syntax.

Comment: That's why I was asking, I spent a decent amount of time googling around and couldn't find a good example of a multiple or ldap query...a link to an example may end up being the correct answer.

And a bunch of ors is exactly what I'm looking for....

Comment: The best I can find is [link](http://download.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/basics/directory/filter.html) and, from what I'm seeing, I think my initial suggestion was incorrect. It appears that you have it correct how you are doing it.

Comment: That's the best link I could find as well, thank you for doing a little digging!

Comment: Use something like Softerra's LDAP Browser, and test in situ? Also who is the back end here? You have a LOT of OR queries - perhaps the LDAP Server is just simply rejecting the query for complexity or lack of indexes. Try just 3 OR'd terms at a time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was a permissions issue. The account created did not have access to the attributes I was searching. I would be interested to know what the expected result of a query on attributes the authenticated user doesn't have access to are, if anyone out there wants to post that would be great. Otherwise I guess I learned a little about LDAP through this whole deal, thanks for taking the time to try and help!

Comment: If you can't read an attribute you won't get a search match on it.

Answer (score 1):

Your filter syntax is correct as per RFC 4515. I suggest you don't put the test values in the search string. Use the {0}, {1} notation and supply the values as arguments to search(). You may be running up against paginated search results when you get fewer than expected. I would test your filters with an independent LDAP client such as JXplorer.

Comment: I posted some code around my query, my guess is that the result.hasMore() is a non-blocking call that doesn't let all the results get back before it adds what it has to the searchResults list. BUT....I'm fairly new to this so that may not be true at all.

Comment: @bwags another issue is that you aren't closing the NamingEnumeration. You really do need to do this, in a finally block, otherwise you can get connection leaks.