# Understanding LDAP OR filter

Tags: ldap

I'm trying to understand OR LDAP queries (specifically Blind LDAP injection).

Am I right in saying that in order to infer about the value objectClass can assume (here `U`) the following filter sent to the LDAP server, is correct?

```
(|(objectClass=void)(objectClass=U))(&(objectClass=void)(type=P*))
```

Supposing the web application returns an object, can I safely say that the LDAP directory includes a category called U?...Is my reasoning correct?

Thanks a lot

Comment: 11 years later: "(|(objectClass=U)(&(objectClass=void)(type=P*)))" means "objectClass is U, *OR* objectClass is void and type is P*"

Answer (score 1):

> Is my reasoning correct?

No. 'Or' is 'or'. As you have written it, either (i) the object class will be void (whatever that means), or (ii) the object class will be U.

The remainder of the filter isn't valid. There is an inner `OR` filter and an inner `AND` filter, but there is no outer operator to state how they are joined. A filter parser might be justified in stopping at the first `))` for example, as there is no valid continuation of the parse.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to understand the OR-operator (per se) inside a LDAP-query, I found the article "[or-operator in LDAP queries](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/45814a44-9f95-486c-b69d-2f204a7406b0/or-operator-in-ldap-queries?forum=winserverDS)"  very helpful:

> To summarize, "&" is the "And" operator, "!" is the "Not" operator,
>   "|" is the "Or" operator, and "*" is the wildcard. Conditions can be
>   nested in parentheses. The wildcard cannot be used in DN attributes.

**Example**: `(|(givenName=foo*)(middlename=foo*)(mail=foo*))` implements a threefold `OR` gives back all occurrences, where `foo` appears in eather the given name, the middlename, or the mail address. For more details, see post "[LDAP multiple or syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6430597/)".

Comment: Dear downvoter, be so kind and let me know your critics, please.

Comment: Best answer is this.